# Altering page setups within postponed blocks

Tags: header-footer, context, backgrounds

I'm using `\startpostponing`–`\stoppostponing` to add two pages that interrupt the flow of normal text. [When I was splitting the text manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75473/making-a-centrefold-figure), the interrupting pages used `\setupfooter` and `\setupbackgrounds`. Neither of these commands appear to work inside the postponing block: the setups are ignored within the block and use the setups of the page before where the postponed page is eventually placed. The postponing commands themselves are undocumented, making research that much harder. Additionally, the pages have different backgrounds, so changing a global definition attached to the postponing block doesn't help.

How do I define individual page setups for postponed pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat tricky because of the way in which postponing is implemented. Since all you want is to set the footer state to stop (and manually insert a background image), an alternative option could be to change the page layout so that the footer space is zero, so that no footer is displayed. The easiest way to achieve that is to set the layout of a specific page using `\setuplayout`.

Consider the following example (I assume that you want to postpone to page 3).

```
\definelayout[default]
             [header=3\lineheight,
             footer=3\lineheight] % To exagerate the effect

\definelayout[none]
             [header=\zeropoint,
              footer=\zeropoint]

\definelayout[3][none] % Set layout of page 3 to be `none`.

\startpostponing[3]
  \startframedtext
      \input knuth
  \stopframedtext
  \page 
\stoppostponing

\setuppapersize[A5]
\showframe % To see the layout

\setuplayout[default]

\starttext
\dorecurse{15}{\input ward \endgraf}
\stoptext
```

Comment: This *almost* works. If I use `[3]` instead of `[none]` in the second define and don't bother with the third, it works. I suspect the `[page-number][named-layout]` argument format isn't supported. Mind if I edit it to reflect those changes?

Comment: Which version of ConTeXt are you using? I testing my solution on `2012.07.19`.

Comment: I also tested the above example on `2012.10.02` and get the correct output in that case as well.

Comment: TeXLive 2010 for OS X. I had unfortunate breakages trying to update to 2011, and haven't braved 2012 yet. In any case this solved my problem and if it's correct for the up-to-date distribution, that's better—and the comments will help anyone who's stuck with 2010. Accepted!

Comment: Are you using MkII or MkIV! ConTeXt MkIV has been almost reimplemented from scratch since 2010. At some stage you will need to bite the bullet and move to a newer version. One suggestion is to try to install ConTeXt minimals (which can be installed in parallel to TL), so that if you can still fall back to TL if something breaks with the latest version.

Comment: Goodness, I really am behind! This doc is an old MkII one, but otherwise I'm using MkIV (though even in that I had to make the above alterations). I guess I need to schedule some mucking-about time soon…